# SQL join two tables matching only 1 row to 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I'm looking for ... lack of a better word, an "exclusive join". I want only 1 row from the right to match a row on the left and cannot be joined to another preceding row. Solution should be for MS SQL 2012.

Example: I have two tables A and B each with 10 rows. Row A1 matches B3 and B5, and Row A3 matches B3 and B5. Result set should include 2 rows: A1 joined to B3 (because it's the first match on the right), and A3 joined to B5 (because it's the first match on the right that hasn't already been used).

Obviously, I'm trying to avoid cursors. Perhaps a recursive CTE is the only other way to go about this?

Comment: without showing the table structure and the queries you tried so far..it is difficult to answer.

Comment: In order to help you we need at least tables' schema and FK relationships between the two tables.

Comment: Look up how Left and Right joins work.

Comment: I think a `cross join` cán do the trick, without a column to join on. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to apply a `row_number` call to the join column, and then add a condition on it when you join:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY join_col ORDER BY 1) rn
        FROM   table_a) a
JOIN   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY join_col ORDER BY 1) rn
        FROM   table_b) b ON a.join_col = b.join_col AND a.rn = b.rn
```

Comment: Was thinking this of this exact solution as I was reading the question. A bit bizarre for sure but certainly in the realm of possibilities.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See the script beneath. CTE and cursor are not knockout demands I understand... Anyway, I hope it leads to your answer.

`Without a identifier to join on` (as not provided in your question, I think a `cross join` is needed, and `partition by` will do the trick.

Something like this:

```
create table #t (a nvarchar(2),rna int, b nvarchar(2), rnb int)

insert into #t select * from
(select a 
    ,row_number() over (partition by a order by a) rna
    ,b
    ,row_number() over (partition by b order by b) rnb
from table_a
cross join
table_b     
) as x
where rnb=1

select a, b from #t 
drop table #t
```

---

And here a script to create the tables:
    create table table_a (a nvarchar(2)) 
    insert into table_a values ('A1'),('A3');

```
create table table_b (b nvarchar(2)) 
insert into table_b values ('B3'),('B5');
```